# Mysql RAND dependent on another field's max value

Tags: mysql

I am using `MySQL`, I have a table having four columns i.e. `id, userid, actualitems` and `performeditems`.

I do have values in `actualitems` column and depending on which I want to generate values of `performeditems` which must not be greater than the `actualitems` but at least should be from 60% to 100% of `actualitem` it `actualitem` value is a positive integer.

For example, if `actualitems` have value 0 then `performeditems` will be 0, but if `actualitems` is 10 then `performeditems` must be any value from 6 to 10.

I have tried like:

```
SELECT id, userid, actualitems, FLOOR((RAND() * actualitems)*0.60) AS performeditems 
FROM engagements;
```

But seems not working, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a random value between range use this:

```
SELECT Round((rand() * (Max-Min)) + Min);
```

which in your case:

```
Round(rand() * (actualitems-actualitems*0.6)) + actualitems*0.6) As performeditems
```